# Lattice ispLSI CLPD dump/transfer hex file

Tags: semiconductors, repair, programmer, lattice

I have two boards that contain Lattice [ISPLSI1016-60LT44](https://www.latticesemi.com/-/media/LatticeSemi/Documents/DataSheets/ispLSI/ispLSI1016DataSheet.ashx?la=en), one is dead in short circuit (is is very hot when powered also), one is on working condition. Even though this part is discontinued by the manufacturer, there is still some in [stock](https://www.digipart.com/part/ISPLSI%201016-60LT44) around the world. I have found official [programmers](https://sk.farnell.com/search?st=hw-usbn-2) named HW-USBN-2A (also discontinued) and a newer HW-USBN-2B (still supported). There are a lot of [clones](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=hw-usbn-2a&_sacat=0&LH_BIN=1&_sop=15) of the former at eBay.

Atmel (Microchip) AVR devices contain lock-bits that can prevent dumping the hex file (you can only erase the whole chip if they are set in the right way). However, if not set, you can dump hex from the working one and burn it into the fresh one.

If I replace the damaged part with the new one and use the HW-USBN-2A eBay clone, would I be able to perform the repair? I did not order anything yet and I would like to calculate the price needed for diagnosis and eventual repair.

**EDIT**
I have found in the programming [documentation](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/components/latticeSemiconductor/_dataBooks/1992_Lattice_pLSI_and_ispLSI_Data_Book_and_Handbook.pdf) that there is a thing called `Security Cell`, which I believe is the equivalent of the fuse lock-bits.

What is the easiest/fastest way to check if the Security Cell is enabled (thus preventing the code trasnfer) ?

Comment: What gives you the idea that on the faulty PCB, it is the ISPLSI chip that broken?

Comment: @StefanWyss Thank you for the comment. I have stated in the Q that is is really hot, far hotter than it should be. Please just focus on the feasibility of the replacement, if possible.

Comment: It was 20 years ago when I worked last with Lattice CPLDs and I think I remember that I was able to verify the chip, but not to read out the code. I know this does not help you much, but I just doubt that you can read back code at all.